# What can I do to improve memory search speed?

Tags: c++, string-search

So... I have this function to search memory for byte pattern, which works great, but at this time, it's pretty slow... is there anything I can do to it to make it faster (as I'm still getting the grips of C++)? Is it possible to scan memory faster than this?

```
BOOL MemoryManager::MemSearch(BYTE * bSearchData, int nSearchSize, DWORD_PTR dwStartAddr, DWORD_PTR dwEndAddr, BOOL bIsCurrProcess, int iSearchMode, std::vector<DWORD_PTR> &vRet) {
BYTE* pCurrMemoryData = NULL;
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION    mbi;
std::vector<MEMORY_REGION> m_vMemoryRegion;
mbi.RegionSize = 0x1000;
DWORD dwAddress = dwStartAddr;

while (VirtualQueryEx(hProcess, (LPCVOID)dwAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)) && (dwAddress < dwEndAddr) && ((dwAddress + mbi.RegionSize) > dwAddress)) {
    if ((mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT) && ((mbi.Protect & PAGE_GUARD) == 0) && (mbi.Protect != PAGE_NOACCESS) && ((mbi.AllocationProtect & PAGE_NOCACHE) != PAGE_NOCACHE)) {
        MEMORY_REGION mData = { 0 };
        mData.dwBaseAddr = (DWORD_PTR)mbi.BaseAddress;
        mData.dwMemorySize = mbi.RegionSize;
        m_vMemoryRegion.push_back(mData);
    }
    dwAddress = (DWORD)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize;
}

std::vector<MEMORY_REGION>::iterator it;
for (it = m_vMemoryRegion.begin(); it != m_vMemoryRegion.end(); it++) {
    MEMORY_REGION mData = *it;

    DWORD_PTR dwNumberOfBytesRead = 0;

    if (bIsCurrProcess) {           
        pCurrMemoryData = (BYTE*)mData.dwBaseAddr;
        dwNumberOfBytesRead = mData.dwMemorySize;
    } else {
        pCurrMemoryData = new BYTE[mData.dwMemorySize];
        ZeroMemory(pCurrMemoryData, mData.dwMemorySize);            
        ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)mData.dwBaseAddr, pCurrMemoryData, mData.dwMemorySize, &dwNumberOfBytesRead);                  

        if ((int)dwNumberOfBytesRead <= 0) {
            delete[] pCurrMemoryData;
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (iSearchMode == 0) {
        DWORD_PTR dwOffset = 0;
        int iOffset = MemFind(pCurrMemoryData, dwNumberOfBytesRead, bSearchData, nSearchSize);
        while (iOffset != -1) {
            dwOffset += iOffset;
            vRet.push_back(dwOffset + mData.dwBaseAddr);
            dwOffset += nSearchSize;
            iOffset = MemFind(pCurrMemoryData + dwOffset, dwNumberOfBytesRead - dwOffset - nSearchSize, bSearchData, nSearchSize);
        }
    } else if (iSearchMode == 1) {
        DWORD_PTR dwOffset = 0;
        int iOffset = SundaySearch(pCurrMemoryData, dwNumberOfBytesRead, bSearchData, nSearchSize);

        while (iOffset != -1) {
            dwOffset += iOffset;
            vRet.push_back(dwOffset + mData.dwBaseAddr);
            dwOffset += nSearchSize;
            iOffset = MemFind(pCurrMemoryData + dwOffset, dwNumberOfBytesRead - dwOffset - nSearchSize, bSearchData, nSearchSize);
        }
    }

    if (!bIsCurrProcess && (pCurrMemoryData != NULL)) {
        delete[] pCurrMemoryData;
        pCurrMemoryData = NULL;
    }
}
return TRUE;
}
```

EDIT: added MemSearch & SundaySearch for reference:

```
int MemFind(BYTE *buffer, int dwBufferSize, BYTE *bstr, DWORD dwStrLen)
{
if (dwBufferSize <0)
{
    return -1;
}
DWORD  i, j;
for (i = 0; i < dwBufferSize; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < dwStrLen; j++)
    {
        if (buffer[i + j] != bstr[j] && bstr[j] != '?')
            break;
    }
    if (j == dwStrLen)
        return i;
}
return -1;
}

int SundaySearch(BYTE* bStartAddr, int dwSize, BYTE* bSearchData, DWORD      dwSearchSize)
{
if (dwSize < 0)
{
    return -1;
}
int iIndex[256] = { 0 };
int i, j;
DWORD k;

for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    iIndex[i] = -1;
}

j = 0;
for (i = dwSearchSize - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (iIndex[bSearchData[i]] == -1)
    {
        iIndex[bSearchData[i]] = dwSearchSize - i;
        if (++j == 256)
            break;
    }
}
i = 0;
BOOL bFind = FALSE;
j = dwSize - dwSearchSize + 1;
while (i < j)
{
    for (k = 0; k < dwSearchSize; k++)
    {
        if (bStartAddr[i + k] != bSearchData[k])
            break;
    }
    if (k == dwSearchSize)
    {
        bFind = TRUE;
        break;
    }
    if (i + dwSearchSize >= dwSize)
    {

        return -1;
    }
    k = iIndex[bStartAddr[i + dwSearchSize]];
    if (k == -1)
        i = i + dwSearchSize + 1;
    else
        i = i + k;
}
if (bFind)
{
    return i;
}
else
    return -1;

}
```

In this case, I'm using **SundaySearch**

Thanks!

Comment: "faster" usually indicates a lack of problem awareness. Please explain how fast you need it to be. What is it you need to achieve by faster methods? Is there a time limit? Did you benchmark?

Comment: By faster methods I need to lower the scan time, right now it takes between 5-6 to 10 seconds to do a scan. It also uses about 20% CPU on average. I would need to lower the scan time for faster updates... CPU consumption lowering would also be great... and since I'm an amateur, I wonder if I could have improved the code or if I've done this right and these are normal times.

Comment: Well... how big is the area you are searching?  How big is the sequence you are searching for?  Are you using a string matching algorithm or just naive search checking every byte in the haystack for the first byte of your needle?

Comment: Could you explain better, I don't understand why you can't use memcmp

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure its possbile. But why not benchmark the code, find the hot path and see what *you* can reasonably do to optimize it? Apart from this, just some ideas, because I only skimmed through the code.

- Can you preallocate the memory once instead of allocating in the loop?
  See `rMemoryData = new BYTE[mData.dwMemorySize];`
- Is zeroing really necessary?
  See `ZeroMemory(pCurrMemoryData, mData.dwMemorySize);`
- Can you `vector::reserve()` some elements for your `vRet` or is it unpredictable
  and you rather risk allocating on `push_back()`?
- Are you confident your search algorithm is good? See `MemFind()` and `SundaySearch()` ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add those as reference, added MemFind and SundaySearch - I'm using SundaySearch in this case.